# Azure app service with python from a visual studio project

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-app-service-plans

We have a python application (Flask) that we develop with Visual Studio.
We push this to Azure DevOps as a git.

When I push it to our Azure App Service it only works when I only push the actual python files and not the `.vs` folder or the `.pyproj`, `.pyproj.user` files. This means I have a folder locally that I copy the files to and then push to app services. That is not the nicest solution as you can imagine.

My questions:

1. Why does app service not work with the "other" files?
2. How would this work nicely that every time I push directly to the app service as well as our Azure DevOps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. not sure I understand the question properly. but you dont need to push those to the webapp for it to work. you can use gitignore file to exclude those not needed files from commits.
2. you can configure you webapp to use local git deployment method and do a push "directly", but that is probably not what you want to do. you probably want to build on commit to git\vsts\whatever repo and push artifacts to the webapp

Comment: Thanks for the .gitignore remark. I was taking it entirely wrong, had to just make good .gitignores and keep the "bullshit VS" files locally never putting them in any git repo. (And I think a .pyc might have killed the app service as wel....)